# Thrift (de)serialization of list

Tags: java, serialization, thrift

In Thrift, in the context of a method call on a service, lists can be used directly as arguments or return type. If you need explicit object (de)serialization, is there a convenient way (in Java) to use Thrift for (de)serializing a List< TBase > without having to wrap this as a separate struct in the thrift IDL?

More concretely, suppose I have defined in thrift

```
struct A {
    1: required long x;
    2: required long y;
}
```

I can (de)serialize a list of these by defining

```
struct ListOfA {
    1: required list<A> theList;
}
```

and then

```
ListOfA myList = ...
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer();
byte[] mySerializedList = serializer.serialize(myList);
```

My question is whether it's possible to avoid this (slightly inelegant) definition of an extra struct only to contain the list.

The following does not work as TSerializer.serialize expects a TBase

```
List<A> myList = ...   // List<A> instead of ListOfA
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer();
byte[] mySerializedList = serializer.serialize(myList); //does not compile
```

Using a typedef in the IDL would already help but these are not translated into a Java class it seems

```
typedef list<A> ListOfA
```

=> ListOfA is not defined in the generated Java code.

Comment: If you think you found a bug you are free to file a JIRA ticket including a test case.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether it's possible to avoid this (slightly inelegant) definition of an extra struct only to contain the list

I would recommend the opposite: do the "inefficient" step of using a wrapping struct.

Thrift allows for an arbitrary number of input arguments. However, there can be **only one return value**. There are no such things as `var` or `out` parameters, or multiple return values, therefore you are really limited to a maximum of one return value to return whatever data you need to return.

The second aspect that comes into play is **soft-versioning**. Thrift allows for enhancing the interfaces and data structures later on, without breaking older services or clients. If you decide to do this

```
struct Bar { /*some data*/ }

service Foo {
    list<Bar> GiveMeTheData()
}
```

you essentially cut yourself off from that mechanism. Because the returned `list<Bar>` cannot be extended with new additional members. You will have to add another call in that case.

In contrast, by using a wrapping `struct`, extending the return data is easily possible, and the price to pay is not that high:

```
struct Bar { /*some data*/ }

struct FooResult { 
  1: list<Bar>   list
  // new members here
}

service Foo {
    FooResult GiveMeTheData()
}
```

Futhermore, the latter also allows for returning a NULL list, which would not be possible with the first layout.